# Мультиплатформенность

Tags: .net, avalonia

При выборе шаблона проекта написано Windows Linux MacOs а в целевой ОС ничего не указано и там упоминания linux нет а Windows есть . Что бы это значило и основной вопрос , теряется ли мультиплатформенность (интересует Linux и Windows) при подключении Windows Forms к проекту ? Linux при этом вылетает или нет ?

Comment: `при подключении Windows Forms к проекту` - да, `WinForms` наботает только на Windows

Comment: Спасибо Exploding Kitten , а у Вас случайно нет опыта Linux ? вроде для него есть свой фрэйм вопрос нужно ли создавать программу в линуксе или созданная в вин будет работать в линуксе ? для меня это не знакомая тема , спасибо .

Comment: на .net консольные и веб приложения будут работать и на windows, и на linux, для десктопных приложений можно использовать avalonia (он кроссплатформенный), ну или maui (пока там поддержки linux нет, вроде должна появиться)

Comment: Спасибо Exploding Kitten .